# How to centralize relative position element without fix width in a div?

Tags: html, css

I have to display text above of the image to make it looks like the snooker ball (number on top of the ball) with the HTML and CSS as below, I can easily modify the image height&width by just changing the container height and width. It is working fine! Below is yellow ball and blue ball.

## HTML

```
<div class="resultNumberContainer">
<img src="images/yellowBall.png" />
<span class="numberText">1</span>
</div>

<div class="resultNumberContainer">
<img src="images/blueBall.png" />
<span class="numberText">5</span>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.resultNumberContainer
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.resultNumberContainer img
{
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    height: auto;
}

.numberText
{
    text-align:center;
    color: White;
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    height: auto; 
}
```

The balls have to display in 1 of the column of the table. so here has 3 columns : 2 snooker balls, column 2, and column 3.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="margin: 0 auto;background-color:green;width:100%;height:auto;">

    <div class="resultNumberContainer">
    <img src="images/num_blue_small2.png" />
    <span class="numberText">1</span>
    </div>

    <div class="resultNumberContainer">
    <img src="images/num_blue_small2.png" />
    <span class="numberText">1</span>
    </div>
</div>

</td>
<td>column 2</td>
<td>column 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

By default, the element in the columns are display on left. I want to make it to display on center. By setting **td** or **tr** to **text-align:center** , it only works for column 2 and 3, but snooker balls does not look nice. 
What should I do ?

Comment: Where's the HTML for your table? Also, why are you using a table?

Comment: do you have a problem within your table or above code?

Comment: I have just edited my question. I have to display other data such as id, date and etc in other columns. The resultnumbercontainer is in one of the column

Comment: @melati Just wrote an answer...try and explain in comments there.

Comment: @APAD1 please check for the updated question :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from "hence I have to set it to stand on centre of the row",

You should use

```
tr
{
text-align:center;
}
```

instead of `td`.

Comment: either use text-align:center in tr or td, it is not working fine. Is it because the resultNumberContainer , the image and numberText is in relative and absolute position respectively?

Comment: @melati my apologies..but Didn't understand properly.

Comment: I didn't see you use any td or tr tags. If you are using div's you could try 
display: table-cell; I am not 100% sure what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: @user3830694  , i just edited my question, can understand better?

Comment: @eg_dac I have added in the table in my question, please have a look.. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

New code [here to test](http://jsfiddle.net/jxPa9/2/). if this isn't what you want, then i can't figure out what you are trying to do. maybe you can provide an image or something that you wish to achieve.

```
Updated the code for the fiddle.
```

Comment: nope.. it does not looks fine... it does not align to center of the row. Thanks for the effort !